# Trouble with concatenation involving text and variables?

Tags: php

Here's the instructions: If true, set $price variable to contain the concatenation of a text string (“SALE PRICE:”) and the discounted price calculated by multiplying the regular price by 90%. Concatenated with a `<BR />` and a text string (“REG. PRICE:”) and the regular price of the item.

Here's what I've tried:

`$price = echo ('SALE PRICE: $' . $discount . 'REG. PRICE: $' . $item->item_cost);`

And all I get is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO"

I've tried googling when to use single and double quotes, but I feel like I'm just interchanging them and not making much of a difference. I saw another thread that was helpful in explaining when to use each type of quote and periods, but I don't think I applied the knowledge properly because I still kept getting an error. Any advice would help.

Comment: Is $price a javascript variable? I'm assuming not.  Why not just `$price = "Sale price: $".$discount... ` and then later `echo $price`

Comment: Tip: You're placing the wagon before the horse. `$wagon = echo` ;-) it needs to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is not a function in PHP. It is a language construct. You cannot assign its return value. Try without it:

```
$price = 'SALE PRICE: $' . $discount . 'REG. PRICE: $' . $item->item_cost;
```

Comment: `echo $price=...` is valid, which is what I feel is what the OP intended to do.

Comment: You are right, what he probably wanted is to print after concatenating the string. What I sated is that the return value of echo cannot be assigned to a variable as in the example code (because there is no return value). And that stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = 'SALE PRICE: $' . $discount . 'REG. PRICE: $' . $item->item_cost;

echo $price;
```